# BLE for windows 7 and C# .net 4.5

Tags: c#, windows-7, bluetooth-lowenergy

Can any please suggest any Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) dongle for windows 7 and also the stack for the same that works with C# .net 4.5. 
I need to communicate with multiple devices using BLE connection simultaneously. 
Multiple simultaneous data transfers is the core need.
Any help is highly appreciated.